# Guardar resultados de un array

Tags: php

Mi codigo recibe unos resultados como muestro a continuacion

```
$a=("es: $f, es1:$f1, es2:$f2, es3:$f3, es4:$f4, es5:$f5 ,es6:$f6, es7:$f7 " );
$array = explode(",", $a);
$output = print_r( $array, true ) ;  
$longitud = count($array);
//echo"$longitud";
for($i=0; $i<$longitud; $i++)
  {
        echo $array[$i];
        echo "<br>";
}
```

cuando realizo esto obtengo :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

una de las cosas que intente sin resultado es obtener solo los valores que tengan  en este caso seria es2:2019-09-30 y es7:2019-09-29 colocando un if dentro del for ,si alguno me podria ayudar.Muchas gracias

Comment: He probado el codigo en mi pc y el resultado se optiene de manera correcta. Debes tener algun problema a la hora de añadir los valores a todos los `$f,$f1,$f2,$f3,$f4,$f5,$f6,$f7` ya que si creas las variables y le aplicas un valor se ejecuta correctamente el codigo. Checa que tu codigo este asignando bien los valores. Tambien deberias aclarar bien tu pregunta porque no se entiende demasiado a lo que quieres llegar.

Comment: el formato que presentas se parece mucho al serializer de php. Puedes poner un ejemplo real de los datos que te llegan? quizas se pueda simplificar con el `unserializer` propio de php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Otra posible solución sería haciendo uso de la [función `validateDate` propuesta en las notas de contribución del Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.checkdate.php#113205).

Lo que haremos aquí será:

1. Crear un array asociativo organizado, donde las claves serán los valores `es...` y los valores lo que está después de ellos.
2. Recorrer ese array, pasando a cada uno de sus valores la función `validateDate` que nos dirá si es una fecha o no.

#### Ventajas

- Obtendremos un array organizado con la cadena inicial por si lo necesitamos para otras cosas.
- Estaremos trabajando sobre seguro con las fechas, dado que `validateDate` hace uso de la clase `DateTime`

Este sería el código:

```
$a=("es: , es1:2, es2:2019-09-30, es3:2, es4:, es5:2 ,es6:, es7:2019-09-29 " );

#Array final organizado
$mData = array();

#Separamos los elementos primero por la coma
foreach (explode(',', $a) as $mItem){
    #Separamos los sub-elementos por los : para crear arreglo asociativo
    $mParts = explode(':', $mItem);
    
    #Asignamos como llave el índice 0 y como valor el índice 1
    #Y limpiamos los espacios sobrantes con trim
    $mData[trim($mParts[0])] = trim($mParts[1]);
}

#Usamos el array organizado para verificar sus valores
foreach ($mData as $k=>$v){
    echo (validateDate($v)) ? "El valor en $k es fecha: $v\n": "El valor en $k no es fecha: $v\n";
}

function validateDate($date, $format = 'Y-m-d')
{
    $d = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date);
    return $d && $d->format($format) == $date;
}
```

**Salida:**

```
El valor en es no es fecha: 
El valor en es1 no es fecha: 2
El valor en es2 es fecha: 2019-09-30
El valor en es3 no es fecha: 2
El valor en es4 no es fecha: 
El valor en es5 no es fecha: 2
El valor en es6 no es fecha: 
El valor en es7 es fecha: 2019-09-29
```

Y en `$mData` tenemos un array asociativo ordenado. Si hacemos una prueba:

```
print_r($mData);
```

**Salida:**

```
Array
(
    [es] => 
    [es1] => 2
    [es2] => 2019-09-30
    [es3] => 2
    [es4] => 
    [es5] => 2
    [es6] => 
    [es7] => 2019-09-29
)
```

---

### Un array sólo con fechas válidas

Supongamos que lo que interesa es crear un array sólo con los elementos que tienen fechas válidas. Podríamos hacer lo siguiente:

```
$a=("es: , es1:2, es2:2019-09-30, es3:2, es4:, es5:2 ,es6:, es7:2019-09-29 " );

#Array final con las fechas únicamente
$mDates = array();


#Separamos los elementos primero por la coma
foreach (explode(',', $a) as $mItem){
    #Separamos los sub-elementos por los : para crear arreglo asociativo
    $mParts = explode(':', $mItem);
    
    #Asignamos como llave el índice 0 y como valor el índice 1
    #Y limpiamos los espacios sobrantes con trim
    $mKey=trim($mParts[0]);
    $mValue=trim($mParts[1]);
    
    #Validamos directamente aquí
    if (validateDate($mValue)){
        #Si es fecha válida lo introducimos en el array
        $mDates[$mKey]=$mValue;
    }
}

#La función de validación
function validateDate($date, $format = 'Y-m-d')
{
    $d = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date);
    return $d && $d->format($format) == $date;
}

print_r($mDates);
```

**Salida:**

```
Array
(
    [es2] => 2019-09-30
    [es7] => 2019-09-29
)
```

Comment: genial es la solucion que estaba buscando pero necesito esas dos fechas poder guardarlas en dos variables por ejemplo $V1= 2019-09-30 y $V2=2019-09-29

Comment: @GuidoBenicio ¿podrías decir el uso posterior que le darás? Ahí ya las tienes en un array, recorriendo ese array sacas las fechas. También en este bloque: `if (validateDate($mValue)){
        #Si es fecha válida lo introducimos en el array
        $mDates[$mKey]=$mValue;
    }` las tendrías a mano, sería el valor de `$mValue`. Ahora bien, *guardarlas en una variable* se puede entender de mil modos. Todo depende del uso. Lo que se suele hacer es pasar el array `$mDates` al escenario donde necesites la información y recorrer el array para sacar las fechas.

Comment: es para que esas fechas pueda usarlas para hacer una consulta en un base de datos

Comment: Por eso te decía. En ese caso, puedes crear un array simplemente así: `$mDates(valor1, valor2, valorN)` y luego usas `implode` si lo que necesitas es una consulta del tipo `SELECT * FROM laTabla WHERE laFecha IN(valor1, valor2, valorN)`. O sea, es cuestión de adaptar el resultado final al uso posterior que le darás.

Answer (score 1):

Para comprobar si es una fecha puedes usar `checkdate` en `php`, con cuidado de ordenar adecuadamente los elementos día, mes y año en función del formato de fecha de tus datos. Puedes ver más detalle [aquí](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.checkdate.php).

Añado un ejemplo de comprobación con tu código:

```
$a=("es: , es1:2, es2:2019-09-30, es3:2, es4:, es5:2 ,es6:, es7:2019-09-29 " );
$array = explode(",", $a);
$output = print_r( $array, true ) ;  
$longitud = count($array);
//echo"$longitud";
for($i=0; $i<$longitud; $i++) {
    $a_elem = explode(":",$array[$i]);
    if (strpos($array[$i],"-")!==false) {
    $a_date = explode("-",$a_elem[1]);
    if (checkdate($a_date[1],$a_date[2],$a_date[0])) {
        echo "Es fecha ".$array[$i]."<br>";
    } else {
        echo "No es fecha ".$array[$i]."<br>";
    }
    } else {
        echo "No hay elemento tipo fecha ".$array[$i]."<br>";
    }
}
```

Resultado:
No hay elemento tipo fecha es:

```
No hay elemento tipo fecha  es1:2
Es fecha  es2:2019-09-30
No hay elemento tipo fecha  es3:2
No hay elemento tipo fecha  es4:
No hay elemento tipo fecha  es5:2 
No hay elemento tipo fecha es6:
Es fecha  es7:2019-09-29
```

Comment: para guardar los valores que son fechas en dos variables distintas seria solo asignando por ejemplo  $V=$array[$i].Gracias

Comment: @GuidoBenicio si, guardas en una variable diferente si cumple la condición, por ejemplo para guardar en un array $a_confecha[]=$array[$i].